# Custom Chat Messages MCPE

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I see in adventure and custom maps chat messages and in making my own I try the say command, yet whenever I do it has an @ symbol at the start. Then I tried the tellraw command, but it doesn’t exist in MCPE yet so how do I achieve the custom chat messages?

Answer (score 1):

Rename the command block in an anvil. That way you can make it appear as a different name in chat.

Without `tellraw`, you can't remove the name completely.

Comment: There’s a simpler solution. You can make the command block’s name different by editing the “Hover Note” field. Be warned: If you use this trick with a /tell command, the name will be repeated twice.

Comment: @Detmondyou You can write that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There’s a simpler solution. You can make the command block’s name different by editing the “Hover Note” field. Be warned: If you use this trick with a /tell command, the name will be repeated twice.